# Angular return Observable after processing with subscribe

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-observable

In Angular 5 I need to make an HTTP GET call, process the output, and then return that processed output as an Observable itself.  I'm really confused on how to do that.  I'm currently getting/processing the data like so:

```js
this.http.get<BarcodeResponse>(url, {
  headers: this.headers
}).subscribe(x => {
  let barcodes = x.result.map(r => {
    return r.u_space_barcode;
  });
});
```

So now I want to send `barcodes` back as the `Observable<string[]>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
this.http.get<BarcodeResponse>(url, {
headers: this.headers })
  .map(value => {
   //Do the parsing you need
  return value
});
```

Comment: I'm however not quite sure what you mean that you 'want to send barcodes back as the Observable<string[]>'. Do you want to send them back to the api like that? Return it to the component from the service?

Comment: Thanks.  I just had to add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` to my file.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to mix Rxjs `map` operator with the prototype patching method.

You can import it either by 
`import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

or
`import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: Thanks.  I like the second form better that you showed as it's more consistent with the rest of the imports.

Comment: @Gargoyle that's right. It can import more than one operator in one line `import { map, mergeMap, forkJoin } from 'rxjs/operators' `, make code cleaner :)